# Solidity Warning i can't verify my contract for this warning

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, contract-development, remix

Token warning code
Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to view
--> Muscky_Token.sol:20:1:
|
20 | function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Answer (score 0):

You would just have to declare the function like so:

```
function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {...}
```